# Are Dream Job employees a level 9 automatically?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

In the original Tiny Tower if you gave a resident their dream job they performed better than a level 9 for the task even if they were a 3 or 4.

Has anyone been able to verify the same is true in Tiny Death Star?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only benefit I've noticed in my game play is that a bitizen with a dream job stocks double the normal amount of the product they are responsible for. Otherwise, they are the same as a bitizen of their skill level for all other considerations.

I replaced a level 8 dreamer with a simple level 9 and then compared the time it took to complete an order. The time was shorter with the level 9 than the level 8 dreamer. (This is with the recent (Nov 26, 2013) build on Windows 8 OS.)

Comment: My understanding is that the level of the bitizen determines the speed at which they order, and the dream job doubles the amount which they can order at their given level.  In other words, if a level 9 can order 10 units in 1 minute, a dream job level 9 can order 20 units in 1 minute.  But a level 8 could order 10 units in 1.5 minutes, a dream job level 8 could order 20 units in 1.5 minutes, and so on . . .

Comment: The dream job level 8 actually stocks 10 units x2 in 1.5 minutes. That is, he stocks as normal, but ends up with double the amount to sell. The dream job employee isn't actually stocking twice as fast, he just has magic that once he stocks the "10", it then turns into "20" (10 x 2 units).

Comment: In essence, the same ... :-)